# Remove the last digits from numbers which exceed a certain length

Tags: r, gsub, maxlength

I have a vector of zip codes that includes both five and nine digit codes. I want to drop the end digits from codes which exceed a length of five.

For example, the following codes:

```
zip<-c(11566, 46235, 50467, 856073217, 97333, 856159229)
```

should become

```
zip
11566
46235
50467
85607
97333
85615
```

I was thinking gsub would be a good way to fix this, but I can't figure out how to write the code for it. I tried this but it definitely doesn't work.

```
df$zip<- gsub("\\d(!i:5)", "", as.character(df$zip))
```

Comment: You convert to character for the input which is good - I don't know what class your real data is in but beware using `numeric` or `integer` for zip code data - many zip codes start with a `0` which will be dropped if you convert to a numeric data type.

Answer (score 10):

This should work

```
zip<-c(11566, 46235, 50467, 856073217, 97333, 856159229)

> s <- substr(zip,1,5)
> s
[1] "11566" "46235" "50467" "85607" "97333" "85615"

> as.numeric(s)
[1] 11566 46235 50467 85607 97333 85615
>
```

Comment: Yep, regex is overkill for this task.

Comment: I'd skip the `as.numeric()` -- not in this sample data but some zip codes include leading 0s.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sub`.  Capture the first five characters as a group (`(.{5})`) followed by the rest of the characters.  In the replacement, we replace with the backreference.

```
as.numeric(sub("(.{5}).*", "\\1", zip))
#[1] 11566 46235 50467 85607 97333 85615
```

Just to be clear, the `substr` method would be faster than `sub`.  But, as the post was about using `gsub/sub`, this would be helpful.